# How to find the largest images in wordpress post

Tags: images

I have wordpress post with multiple images which are of multiple sizes. I need to find the largest image from the images in the post & set it as featured image.

I know there are plugin that automatically sets the 1st image as featured image, but I need to set the largest images in post as the featured image. how can i do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written code we can check and suggest improvements?

Comment: Are you using standard Wordpress image sizes, or have you set your own?

Comment: Not written any code, The image sizes can be any thing as I pulling data from feed.